# How to show data from place picker to edittext

Tags: android, google-api

Please help. I try to implement Place picker to get address and show in 
EditText. but it still no result and Place picker just shows just a second.

```
addressEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.shippment_address);
location = (Button) findViewById(R.id.location);
location.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
                    try {
                        startActivityForResult(builder.build(ConfirmFinalOrderActivity.this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
                    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
            if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);
                    addressEditText.setText(place.getAddress().toString());
                }
            }
        }
```

This My AndroidManifest.xml, i already added API key

```
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDnH36F4PE0bPgudWkQR3ZEWaKVYjncO1Y" />
```

I have also added dependencies

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything seems okay but have tried taking permissions. 
**FYI** place picker was deprecated on Jan 29th and it will be turned off by July 29 as per Google's documentation. 
Alternatively you can use Autocomplete.
Hope this helps.